# WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

**I created two models user.rb and cart.rb**

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :login

  has_one :cart

end
```

**cart.rb**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

end
```

**when I create a user in rails console, message appears : WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: login**

```
E:\work\my_store>rails c
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)
irb(main):001:0> user1 = User.new(login: "user1")
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: login

=> #<User id: nil, login: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0>
```

**help me to solve this**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a huge difference between `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible` - you want to use the other one. :)

Comment: Sorry, learning from my head starts to not work))) thank you for your reply, it works))

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature in Rails that prevents mass-assignment. If you'd like to whitelist certain attributes you can do

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :login
end
```

Or just not use mass-assignment when creating your models.